# многострочный INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

Есть некоторый массив данных:

`array('number'=>'one', 'time'=>'seven', 'fruit'=>'apple')`

имена ключей заранее не известны.
Так же есть таблица с такими столбцами:

`hash|time|key|val`

hash - это некоторый идентификатор по которому можно выбрать все значения данного массива.
Как одним запросом "вставить" массив в базу?

Answer (score 1):

```
$myArray = [ ваши пары значений];
$db = new mysqli(данные для коннекта);
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO table (hash, key, val) VALUES (?,?,?)';
foreach($myArray as $key => $value){
    $hash = вычисляем нужный хэш;
    $stmt->bind_params('sss', $hash, $key, $value);
    $stmt->execute();
}
$stmt->close();
$db->close();
```

запрос не один, но зато "подготовленный", т.е. отработает достаточно быстро.

**upd** кроме того, вставлять массив заранее неизвестного размера одной операцией крайне опасно. Можно нарваться на физическую невозможность сервера БД переварить очень большой запрос.